# Search Display Controller causing crash

Tags: uitableview, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to set up a searchBar with a TableView so I can filter through the table view, I am trying to do it all programmatically. Although my code keeps sending back the error: `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. The error is inside the `func numberOfRowsInSection`, I have marked it. it is to do with the SearchDisplayController, it is saying it is nil I think? code:

```
struct UserMatches {
    var finalMatchesName : String
    var finalMatchesAge : Int
    var finalMatchesLocation : PFGeoPoint
    var finalMatchesImage : NSData
}

class Matches: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    var tableView = UITableView()
    var searchBar = UISearchBar()

    var userMatches = [UserMatches]()
    var filterUsers = [UserMatches]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createTableView()
    }

    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        self.filterUsers = self.userMatches.filter({(user1: UserMatches) -> Bool in
            let stringMatch = user1.finalMatchesName.rangeOfString(searchText)
            return (stringMatch != nil)
        })
    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController!, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool {
        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchString)
        return true
    }

    func createTableView() {
        tableView.sizeToFit()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

        searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchBar.delegate = self
        searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.Minimal
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
        searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Search
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar

        var searchDispCont = UISearchDisplayController(searchBar: searchBar, contentsController: nil)
        searchDispCont.delegate = self;
        searchDispCont.searchResultsDataSource = self;
        searchDispCont.searchResultsDelegate = self;

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {  //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value 
            return self.filterUsers.count
        } else {
            return self.userMatches.count
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your view controller's `searchDisplayController` property is of type `UISearchDisplayController?` (an optional), and is `nil` inside `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`. When you force unwrap an optional using `!`, your app will throw a runtime exception (the one you're seeing) when the value is `nil`.

The reason the property is `nil` is that you are creating it programmatically and specifying `nil` for the `contentsController` argument. This should most likely be:

```
var searchDispCont = UISearchDisplayController(searchBar: searchBar, contentsController: self)
```

This will implicitly assign it to your view controller's `searchDisplayController` property.

Also, it is worth noting that `UISearchDisplayController` and `UISearchDisplayDelegate` are deprecated in iOS 8, so you should instead be using `UISearchController`.

Comment: Thanks but this still crashes with the exact same error?

Comment: Curious. The docs indicate that the `searchDisplayController` property is set when a `UISearchDisplayController` is initialised. Of course, if `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` is called _before_ you create the search display controller, you will still see the crash, but I can't be sure if that is happening or not... it seems unlikely given that you're creating it before even adding the table view as a subview.

Comment: Would it be something to do with the `self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView` which is referencing to the function isn't it? I have picked this code from other sources so trying to understand what is fully going on...

Comment: Looking at it, I would be surprised if that was the reason. The compiler should be able to distinguish between the property and the method, and I suspect the assignment error is misleading, resulting from the fact that the `searchDisplayController` property is read-only. I would first ensure that the line `var searchDispCont = ...` is called before `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`. Step through with the debugger, and also ensure that `searchDisplayController` is not `nil` after executing that line.

Comment: Ok, I have now managed to get it to run without crashing, as you can see I have edited my code. Although now the numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath both aren't running, can you help?

Comment: You've edited the question to the point that existing answers wouldn't make any sense, which isn't a great idea. Your edited code doesn't seem to make sense - you reference `self.searchDispCont`, but nowhere in your class is such a property declared. Are you sure that `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` isn't being called, or perhaps it's just returning 0 (which would stop other delegate calls). I would suggest you instead need to ask a new question, or perhaps just step through your code more carefully to understand what's going on.